# Prove that $\cdot : GL_2(\mathbb{R}^2) \, \times \, Bil(\mathbb{R}^2) \rightarrow Bil(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is an action

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $Bil(\mathbb{R}^2)$ denote the collection of all bilinear forms on $\mathbb{R}^2$. I need to show that $GL_2(\mathbb{R}^2)$, the general linear group, acts on $Bil(\mathbb{R}^2)$ using the formula $$[g \, \cdot \, B](u,v) = B(g^{-1}u, g^{-1}v)$$ for every $g \in GL_2(\mathbb{R}^2)$, $B \in Bil(\mathbb{R}^2)$, and $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Namely, I need to prove that the map $\cdot : GL_2(\mathbb{R}^2) \, \times \, Bil(\mathbb{R}^2) \rightarrow Bil(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is an action.

I have never shown that a map is an action so I am quite lost on how to use this formula to show the axioms that an action must satisfy, i.e., associativity and identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identity: Suppose that $e \in GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is the identity transformation. Then $e^{-1}$ is also the identity transformation. We can easily see that

$$ [e \cdot B](u,v) = B(e^{-1}u,e^{-1}v) = B(u,v)$$

Thus $e \cdot B = B$, so the identity elements of the general linear group acts trivially on the space of bilinear forms.

Associativity: Let $g,h \in GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$. We'd like to show that for all pairs of vectors $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^2$,

$$[(gh) \cdot B](u,v) = [g \cdot [h \cdot B]](u,v)$$

Can you unravel the definitions to show that this is true?